# Proxy pass Server sent event using nginx

Tags: nginx, server-sent-events

We are trying to implement **SSE** [Server-Sent-Event] for one of our upload file API endpoints.
We have **post /media** endpoint which accept **multipart/form-data**. In form data we are passing the file. The response of the api is a **event stream** i.e. Content-Type is **text/event-stream**.

Example curl request

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://localhost/api/v1/media' --form 'file=@"/home/shivam/Downloads/with_no_cover_image.mp3"'
```

When we are hitting above api **without using Nginx**, we are able to upload files and get proper event stream response [with any file size].

When we are redirecting requests **through Nginx** to the server, we are able to upload files which are having **a size of less than around 2.5 MB**.

When we try to upload a **size bigger than 2.5 MB**, it's not able to upload the complete file on the server.

While **debugging** we found that the server only received **2.5 MB of data** only for the uploaded bigger files.

Please suggest to us what can be a solution here...Thanks !!!

Ref SSE: https://medium.com/geekculture/understanding-server-sent-events-with-node-js-37cfc7aaa7b

Below Nginx config we are using:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}
http {

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;

    server {
         listen 443 ssl;
         server_name localhost;
         client_max_body_size 500M;
            root /home/manoj/instaglitch/build;
             ssl on;
             ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
             proxy_set_header Cookie "";

             ssl_certificate certificate.crt;
             ssl_certificate_key private.key;

            location / {
                    proxy_read_timeout 1h;
                    proxy_connect_timeout 1h;
                    proxy_send_timeout 1h;
                    proxy_set_header Connection '';
                    proxy_http_version 1.1;
                    chunked_transfer_encoding off;
                    proxy_pass https://localhost:8080;
                    proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
                    proxy_set_header Cookie "";
            }
    }
```

}